# phonegap javascript google api doesnt work in apk file

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

ive just started using phonegap and i can manage to see the map in the browser and the phonegap app, but once i convert the project to apk file(in adobe build), it shows nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    hello
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com/ https://maps.gstatic.com/ https://mts0.googleapis.com/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
<style>
    body, html, #map {  margin: 0;width:100%;height:400px }
#map {
    position: relative;
    width:400px;
    height: :50%;
}

#map:after {
    width: 22px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    margin: -40px 0 0 -11px;
    background: url('https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/spotlight-poi_hdpi.png');
    background-size: 22px 40px;  
   pointer-events: none; 
}

    </style>



   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY" async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){

        var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    }, false);



    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

please help me to figure out what is the problem.

Comment: I'd try building for browser if you haven't already (cordova platform add browser), and then opening it from ../project/platforms/browser (the index.html file directly in Chrome/whatever - not through Visual Studio).  Then go to developer options, and take a look at any errors in the Console.

If it's Android specific, it's going to be harder.

Also, make sure whitelist is added in your config.xml.  It automatically does this if you create the project from a Cordova template, but I believe if you use NPM you need to add it manually (I might be wrong here).

Comment: show ur error first

Comment: i dont use cordova or npm, just the phonegap desktop app. And there are no errors in the browser when i run it, i think i dont know how to build the apk file correctly through adobe build website, can you please help me im losing my mind...